# Create multiple relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Q&A app and the thing is, I want to add the ability for people to post answers.

I already built a migration so that the question has the same id of the user with
`rails g migration add_user_id_to_questions` and then added the `has_many/belongs_to` associations.

Now I am stuck with how to create a relationship for the answers.

I already added a answer scaffold with:
`rails g scaffold Answer answer:integer`

And then I did a migration: (Was it a right move? to create a migration so that answers have the same ID as the question?)

`rails g migration add_answer_id_to_answers`

And added the `has_many/belong_to` as well.

But now what? How do I make answer the to have the same ID of the question? Because inside the show view, if a user posts an answer it will basically be visible on every question...

Show view:

```
      <% @answers.each do |answer| %>

      <div class="well bgBlack">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left">
            <% if answer.user.avatar.blank? %>
                <img src="http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png" style="width: 75px;">
            <% elsif answer.user.avatar %>
                <%= image_tag answer.user.avatar, :style => "width:75px;" %>
            <% end %>
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <p class="white"><%= link_to answer.user.username, answer.user, :class => " bg" %></p>
              <p class="white small"><%= answer.answer %></p>
           </div>
           <div class="pull-right">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <% if answer.user_id == current_user.id %>
                        <%= link_to 'delete', answer_path(answer), :method => :delete, :class => "text-muted white" %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>                

      <% end %>
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :answers
end
```

Answer model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Answer controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def create
    @answer = current_user.answers.build(answer_params)
    @answer.save
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def destroy
    @answer.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    def set_answer
      @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:answer)
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you really still working with Ruby on Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

Don't make answers have the same Id as questions, you have to let answers have their own id's, and column that has the questions id to which current answer belongs. 
Just add

```
t.belongs_to :question
```

to your answers migration.

Then run

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION="version of answers migration(numbers in files name)"
```

And to show right answers in questions show view you need to have this in your questions controllers show action

```
def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.answers.all
end
```

Hope this helps :)

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**Edit**

Also add to your questions model

```
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy #if you want assosiated answers to be deleted after you delete question.
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank
```